# Agent Smith Calling Agent Smith

Tags: support, comment, comment-replies

AgentSmith (UserID=1) (not his real name) decides to ask a question at math.stackexchange.com.

Another user with the same name (UserID=2) comments on this question and after a while a third one, also, who guessed it, with the same name (UserID=3).

Now what happens if AgentSmith1 wants to address one specific AgentSmithX with another comment. Who will be notified, when he writes: "@AgentSmith,..."?

We know that "Only one additional @user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified."

So, will it be more than one notification? This would still be in accordance with the status-declined of the feature request: [Allow more than one @name notification per comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/45273/178818)

Since there are plenty of users sharing the same name (there [8 pages](https://math.stackexchange.com/users?page=1&tab=reputation&filter=quarter&search=john) of users named John), did this ever happen?

Comment: Or what will happen if you just write "@use", and there are multiple "user_____"'s in the discussion?

Comment: @TheChaz I recall reading that in case of multiple matches the most recent commenter wins, but can't find the link now. The obvious fix is to spell out the full name. The issue pointed out by draks appears to be more serious: there would be no way to notify the unlucky Agent Smith.

Comment: Points 4 and 5 [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) seem to cover the question on who will be pinged (in other words, what @Leonid said). In any case: if any of your Agent Smiths are *really* interested they will check back with or whithout ping, no?

Comment: @t.b. I just wondered. thanks for the link

Comment: @t.b. Thanks for the link. One can imagine that the discussion involving the agents concluded some weeks ago, and then someone found a crucial flaw in the first Agent's argument. Yeah, not likely.

Comment: You might want to ask how *anon* thinks about this... :)

Comment: There is a feature request related to this at meta.SO: [How to reply to one user among two having same names?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names)

Comment: @J.M. yeah I thought about putting his name instead, but John beat him. [Here](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/51338/how-popular-is-my-name)'s a DB query with a ranking: 1.John, 2.David, 3.Chris...

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think his first name was [John](http://math.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all&search=john+smith)...

Comment: [This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/64425) might be useful in finding out whether such situation already occurred. (I've seen this query in comments in the meta.SO [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125994/how-to-reply-to-one-user-among-two-having-same-names).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Good work it did [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125788/19341), funny...